# Use query_posts() twice and show results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page template for custom post type Activity. Activities are connected to Tours.

In the page template, I want to show Tours with viewed activity, and tours with suggested viewed activity.

Example:

**Tours with Biking:**

#1 #2

**Tours with Biking suggested:**
#5, #6

My code:

```
<?php
$query_string = 'paged='.$paged;
$query_string.= '&orderby=post_date&order=DESC&post_type=tour&meta_query[tour_activities][key]=tour_activities&meta_query[tour_activities][value]='.$current_page_id.'&meta_query[tour_activities][compare]=LIKE&suppress_filters=0&post_status=publish';

parse_str($query_string, $args);
query_posts($args);
?>
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Tours with <?php echo(get_the_title()); ?> suggested</h4>
<?php
$query_string2 = 'paged='.$paged;
$query_string2.= '&orderby=post_date&order=DESC&post_type=tour&meta_query[tour_activities_suggested][key]=tour_activities_suggested&meta_query[tour_activities_suggested][value]='.$current_page_id.'&meta_query[tour_activities_suggested][compare]=LIKE&suppress_filters=0&post_status=publish';

parse_str($query_string2, $args);
query_posts($args);

?>
```

**Problem with my code:**

It only shows the second query **$query_string2** , nothing shows for **$query_string**

How do I use **query_posts()** twice and show results seperately with the same logic of formatting the output in the HTML?

I have custom cards in the page template created by looping through **have_posts()** and then displaying queried Tours

Comment: `query_posts()` overrides the main query and should almost never be used. Use `WP_Query` instead and it'll work fine.